# Easynetq: developer's queues

Tags: c#, rabbitmq, easynetq

Lately we have setup easynetq queues in publish-subscribe and request-response way and common queue connection / endpoint. The goal is setup easynetq in way that developing logic using queue must be independent between  developers - currently we have configured easynetq that every developer machine gets his own prefixed set of queues but it looks like that if 2 ot more developers starts subscribers they read messages from owned queues and also other developers queueus.

How configure easynetq using code to resolve this issue?

Comment: Same question added here: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/issues/743

Answer (score 1):

An easier way to isolate the activities of different developers, as you describe, would be to use a different virtual host (vhost in the connection string) for each developer.  vhosts are completely isolated from each other.

Queues could then have the same name for each developer.  The fact that they are on a different vhost would separate them.

https://www.rabbitmq.com/vhosts.html

Comment: Can it be done in different way? Only using easynetq infrastructure?

Comment: It is possible with separate exchanges and queues, but more work and probably more fragile to administer.  Isolated vhosts is by far the simplest way.  Just one change in the connection string (say, match the vhost name to developer's machine name), and you're done.

Comment: Usual a vhost can just be part of the connection string that you pass EasyNetQ, to connect to RabbitMQ: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Connecting-to-RabbitMQ.  You can administer vhosts through the EasyNetQ wrapper of the RabbitMQ management api too: https://github.com/EasyNetQ/EasyNetQ/wiki/Virtual-Hosts . VHosts are just as much an EasyNetQ thing, as a RabbitMQ thing.  EasyNetQ is only a wrapper of RabbitMQ.

Comment: We have tried 2 solutions: 1. matching queues with exchange - every queue has unique name and unique exchange 2. using virtual hosts and we stick with second solution which is easier to maintain and does not require to use IAdvancedBus